# Error while doing multi batch inference on yolov3 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to do multiple image batch inference on the yolov3 model which is deployed on TensorFlow serving. I can do inference successfully on a single image but when  I pass multiple batches I get an error as

```
InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 6
     [[{{node yolov3/yolo_nms/Squeeze}}]]"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1623673733.762863602","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1061,"grpc_message":"Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 6\n\t [[{{node yolov3/yolo_nms/Squeeze}}]]","grpc_status":3}"
```

saved_model signature is as below

```
The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  inputs['input'] tensor_info:
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      shape: (-1, -1, -1, 3)
      name: serving_default_input:0
```

way I'm passing images are as below

```
load_imgs = load_images_from_dir("/content/yolov3-tf2/image_data/",416,6)
print(load_imgs.shape)
(6, 416, 416, 3)
```

I get an error as above.
I'm this code for  model development from this repository error

> "Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 6
> [[{{node yolov3/yolo_nms/Squeeze}}]]"

causing this is from this [line](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2/blob/3925682b0cc7552fcef72b7b305577b8ad6c839e/yolov3_tf2/models.py#L202).
In general, I read I can pass multiple images as a batch to model but this code giving me an error. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done as model is defined to do inference on batch size 1